# How to show alert popup Yes or No, when user trying to create a duplicate record

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to show alert popup Yes or No, when user trying to create a duplicate record  if user click Yes then duplicate record will save else return to an account page

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard duplicate rules that can give you the flexibility to display existing duplicate records before it allows save the record or do not save it (based on duplicate rules configuration).

[image]

Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_prevention.htm&type=0) and if you are looking for custom popup screen you would need to build custom solution and check examples [1.](https://www.codekiat.com/2019/07/confirm-dialog-in-salesforce-lightning.html) and [2](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092waIAA).

Thanks